# Flatten Column Variables to Yes/No in R and dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, adjacency-matrix

I have a dataset of various people's CVs in a data frame. Each row is a new person entry and there are multiple columns (school, position held, city of birth, etc). I'd like to build an adjacency matrix for these people, so I'm looking into a way to "flatten" the column variables into Yes/No.

For example, a snippet of the data frame looks something like this:

```
Name:     City_of_birth:  Job Title: 
Person1   'New York',     'Librarian'
Person2   'Shanghai',     'Secretary'
Person3   'Tokyo',        'Engineer'
Person4   'Lagos',        'CEO'
Person5   'Atlanta'       'Mayor'
```

I would like to transform the data frame such that there are new column headings 'New York', 'Shanghai', 'Tokyo'... and a Yes/No value associated with each row (person).

```
Name:     New York?:  Shanghai?:  ...    Librarian?:
Person1   Yes         No                 Yes
Person2   No          No                 No
Person3   No          No                 No
Person4   ...
Person5
```

I'm quite new to R, so I am open to using any tool to do this. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

in base R, you could do:

```
a<-table(cbind(df[1],unlist(df[-1])))
a[]<- ifelse(!a,"no","yes")
a
        Atlanta Lagos New York Shanghai Tokyo CEO Engineer Librarian Mayor Secretary
Person1      no    no      yes       no    no  no       no       yes    no        no
Person2      no    no       no      yes    no  no       no        no    no       yes
Person3      no    no       no       no   yes  no      yes        no    no        no
Person4      no   yes       no       no    no yes       no        no    no        no
Person5     yes    no       no       no    no  no       no        no   yes        no
```

Hope this is an easier way to do it. Just arrange all the columns alongside the name variable. Do a table of that, and use `ifelse` where `!a` means `a==0`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to combine the columns together from `City_of_birth` and `Job_Title`. We can create a column with `"Yes"` and then bring the data in wide format using `pivot_wider`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(value = "Yes") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c('City_of_birth', 'Job_Title'), 
              values_from = value, 
              values_fill = list(value = "No"))

# A tibble: 5 x 6
#  Name    NewYork_Librarian Shanghai_Secretary Tokyo_Engineer Lagos_CEO Atlanta_Mayor
#  <fct>   <chr>             <chr>              <chr>          <chr>     <chr>        
#1 Person1 Yes               No                 No             No        No           
#2 Person2 No                Yes                No             No        No           
#3 Person3 No                No                 Yes            No        No           
#4 Person4 No                No                 No             Yes       No           
#5 Person5 No                No                 No             No        Yes
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Name = structure(1:5, .Label = c("Person1", "Person2", 
"Person3", "Person4", "Person5"), class = "factor"), City_of_birth = 
structure(c(3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Atlanta", "Lagos", "NewYork", 
"Shanghai", "Tokyo"), class = "factor"), Job_Title = structure(c(3L, 5L, 
2L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("CEO", "Engineer", "Librarian", "Mayor", 
"Secretary"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```